# C++11 Move heap array into std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, printf, stdstring

Looking around other answers on stackoverflow the answer may just be a no, but please humor me before marking it a duplicate.

So I want to be able for format a string snprintf style as shown below, but only make a single heap allocation.

Lots of examples say to touch the std::String::data() or std::String::c_str() but obviously you shouldn't do this as it's really unsafe, as this is managed memory, so references and pointers are not guaranteed to be constant memory addresses.

Also cannot use std::format as I'm not running C++20

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdio>

std::string Somefunction(const char* formatstring, ...){
    //Let's get the actual size, because recursively reallocating to get this is not efficient
    va_list sizeVl;
    va_start(sizeVl, formatstring);
    const int formatSize = _vscprintf(formatstring, sizeVl);
    va_end(sizeVl);

    if (formatSize < 1){
        return{};
    }

    //Some object to put the memory on the stack, I'll use a char, but could be vector<char> etc, 
    //whatever achieves the goal
    char* tempString = new char[formatSize + 1];

    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, formatstring);
    const int actualLength = vsnprintf(tempString, formatSize, formatstring, vl);
    va_end(vl);

    if (actualLength <= formatSize){
        tempString[actualLength] = '\0';
        //vv--- I really don't want to reallocate on the heap, I already have some heap memory
        //vv--- Move semantics 101
        //std::string output = MOVE(tempString); 
        std::string output("Ideally I move the memory here");
        return output;
    }
    delete[] tempString;
    return{};
}
```

Any thoughts, or is the answer really just std::string isn't the container for you if you want this functionality?

Is there any container I can use safely as a char array in the vsnprintf function that std::String will move safely?

Comment: Since you tagged C++11 is that the standard you are restricted to? So no C++14 or C++17 either?

Comment: Also could you please fix the code sample to actually do what your comments imply? `char* tempString[formatSize + 1];` is not only not heap allocated, but also non-standard VLA (and the wrong type as well)

Comment: Sadly yes, are there answer to this in 14 & 17? Sorry I just banged out the example, will fix

Comment: A lot of stuff in the code doesn't work. Can you please show a [mre] that can actually be compiled? It would also be better if you didn't use so many non-standard features or if you do, then limit the scope of your question to the particular compiler you are using.

Comment: Also, if you simply make `tempString` a `std::string`, then I see only one allocation in the function.

Comment: With C++17 `data()` can return a non-`const` pointer, so then you could just create  a string with the correct size and safely `vsnprintf` into the array returned by `data()` (completely skipping the temporary allocation)

Comment: @user17732522 but you can't give a std::string to vsnprintf, without doing unsafe jank. Hence explaining in the question that I already know the hack ways haha

Comment: @UnholySheep uh neat, one day when we shift our platform to linux I shall get these nice features. But for now C++11 it is

Comment: @Justin If you declare `tempString` as `std::string tempString(formatSize + 1, '\0');` you can pass `&tempString[0]` (or `.data()` since C++17) to `vsnprintf`. Afterwards if you need to adjust the size, you can simply use `resize` which will not reallocate if you are shrinking only.

Comment: @user17732522 Hmmm I didn't realize modifying the operator[] of std::String was considered safe. Nice if it is

Comment: @Justin Yes, since C++11, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/strings#string.require-5.

Comment: It is perfectly OK, safe, and appropriate to modify `string::data()`. If it weren't, it would be `const`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I feel like there is a huge asterisk on that. Hold onto a reference, and push something into the container that causes a reallocate, and tell me your app doesn't crash, when you use your reference

Comment: Did I say you can push new stuff to the string while modifying `data()`? I don't recall such a thing. Obviously, don't do that. Bit I'm sorry, I didn't notice you target C++11. Before C++17, `data()` is `const` and returns a pointer to `const`, you need to use `&string[0]`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. using data() or &string[0] to hand a pointer to a function to update is exactly that. Like because the Q's on here are minimal it's ok in my example, but if there were threads, memory wasn't function scoped, or the function did something more complex, huge risk.

Comment: Do you ever use pass by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in your question are correctly directing you to instantiate a string with a specific size and use the `.data()` or `&[0]` operator to get what you need.

Let me suggest a simpler solution with a constraint. Consider that your output strings have some reasonable length and that you have plenty of stack memory to work with. So use a fixed length temp buffer to do your printf style formatting.  20K is not an unreasonable number of bytes to allocate on the stack.

Then return an instance of a `std::string` using the copy from C string constructor at the very end.

```
std::string Somefunction(const char* formatstring, ...){

   const size_t TEMP_SIZE = 20000;

    va_list vargs = {};

    va_start(vargs, formatstring);

    char buffer[TEMP_SIZE];
    vsnprintf(buffer, TEMP_SIZE, formatstring, vargs);

    va_end(vargs);

    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

You could always increase the buffer size from 20000 to something larger if you needed it. But I'm guessing your strings never get that big. And if they did, you wouldn't want that many bytes in what I'm guessing is your log file.

Comment: I do prefer the stack, but isn't the stack only like 1mb? (platform dependent) 20kb is like 1/50 of your stack gone to a single function?

Comment: What's wrong with that?  You get the stack memory back as soon as the function returns. If you don't have 20KB of stack room to spare, then you got bigger issues.  Stack allocations are instant and O(1).

Comment: This is true, more just thinking out loud. Like if this was your coding style and you had many threads who had functions that did similar things it could add up and get you to the terrible state you highlight.